# js select element not calling function if Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

a call to a function from a select works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <SELECT  onmouseup = "makeplot(this.value)">
        <OPTION value="type1">first choice</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="type2">2nd choice</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="type3">3d choice</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="type4">last choice</OPTION>
    </SELECT>

<script>
function makeplot(word) {
  alert("word is "+word);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `onchange` instead of `onmouseup`! It's the go to option for getting select values when they change. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: no, I want it to fire on every select, not just when the select choice changes.

Comment: i did find a work around using onchange.  I put a dummy option in the select and always change back to it in the function.  But yeck!